# Cytoscape: apply layout only to newly added nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have a Cytoscape graph, and certain user actions can add nodes to the graph. When this happens I want to apply a layout to the new nodes, so that they appear in a reasonable position. However, I want to leave the previously existing nodes at their current positions, since the user might have manually positioned them there.

I found two related questions on Stack Overflow, but they relate to slightly different things:

1) [How to dynamically add nodes to cytoscape graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964733/how-to-dynamically-add-nodes-to-cytoscape-graph) is about adding nodes, but the suggested approach applies the layout to *all* nodes, not only the new ones.

2) [Cytoscape dynamically style last added node only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277834/cytoscape-dynamically-style-last-added-node-only) is about applying styling to new nodes, but I'm interesting in the *positioning* of nodes, not the styling.

An obvious workaround would be to manually specify the position of the new nodes. However, the whole reason layouts exist in the first place is to have a way to calculate decent-looking positions. I'm pretty sure this is possible, I'm just unable to find this anywhere in the Cytoscape documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the layout on [specific elements](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.layout) by using `eles.layout()` There is also `add` [event](http://js.cytoscape.org/#events/collection-events) which is triggered when a new node is added.

Comment: Thank you! Cytoscape is great, but the structure of the documentation sometimes makes it hard to find this information.

Comment: is that `eles` an array or type of Cytoscape object, how to get it?